# Simple proof of that $k[X]^G$ Cohen-Macaualy ($G$ finite)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $X$ be a (EDIT: non-singular, or even $\mathbf A^n$) algebraic variety over a field $k$ (alg. closed). Suppose $G$ is a finite group acting on $X$, $|G|\neq 0$ in $k$. Then $k[X]^G$ is Cohen-Macaulay. All the proofs I've seen are fairly involved.

- Question: is there a simple proof of this fact?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ was Cohen-Macaulay to begin with?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I'm even interested in a simple proof for the case $X = \mathbf A^n$.

Comment: You can see a very simple proof as Theorem 4.3.6 in Benson's "Polynomial Invariants of Finite Groups"; here's a Google Books preview: http://books.google.com/books?id=jxIXivzKFdgC&lpg=PR8&vq=hochster&pg=PA52#v=snippet&q=hochster&f=false

Comment: It's been a while since I thought about it, but my recollection is that "$X$ is non-singular" implies "$k[X]^G$ is Cohen-Macaulay" (Hochster-Roberts) and "X has rational singularities" implies "$k[X]^G$ has rational singularities" (Buto), however, it's not true that "$k[X]$ is Cohen-Macaulay" implies "$k[X]^G$ is Cohen-Macaulay", where $G$ is a reductive algebraic group. Perhaps, the situation is different for a finite group $G$?

Comment: It would be enough to (locally) find a regular sequence consisting of invariants as then $k[X]$ would be free over the subring generated by the sequence and so would $k[X]^G$ being a direct factor of it. It seems that for a polynomial ring the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a general linear polynomial might do the trick.

Comment: Torsten, yes, you can use the polynomials you get from Noether normalization on $k[X]^G$.


Comment: @Steve: Of course (lots of head smacking).